# Center a popup/UserControl

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone

I want to center a PopUp exactly in the center of the screen.
I have used a Usercontrol to display within the popup.
However the way i am calculating HorizontalOffset and vertical offset is wrong.

```
        Popup popUp = new Popup();
        ProgressScreen progressScreen = new ProgressScreen();
        popUp.Child = progressScreen;
        //popUp.HorizontalOffset = (this.ActualWidth/2) + (progressScreen.ActualWidth / 2);
        popUp.VerticalOffset = (this.ActualHeight / 2) + (progressScreen.ActualHeight / 2);
        popUp.HorizontalOffset = (this.ActualWidth - progressScreen.ActualWidth) / 2;
        popUp.Height = this.ActualHeight;
        popUp.Width = this.ActualWidth;
        popUp.IsOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing that this should make it work

`popUp.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Center;`

But in order to work the popup should be placed in a container that occupies the whole screen